# AngularJS: Sort an array of hours and minutes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nvd3.js

I am using nvd3 chart in my angular application. I am getting the labels in below format

```
["14:49", "14:58", "14:57", "14:56", "14:55", "14:54", "14:53", "14:52", "14:51"]
```

I have to sort them based on time.This is my code

```
var hourMin = new Date($scope.items[i].timestamp);
$scope.labels[i] = hourMin.getHours() + ":" + hourMin.getMinutes();
```

**HTML :**

```
<canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="data"
                 chart-labels="labels" chart-legend="true" chart-series="series"
                 chart-click="onClick" >
  </canvas>
```

I have tried `orderBy` but it is not working. Help me.

Comment: when the time is a single digit, do you like to get something like "3:7" for 3 hours and 7 minutes? You should to use a angular filter to convert. If your date is normalized (hh:mm), a single string sort will works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this.......

```
<script>
  angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('test', ['$scope', function($scope){
    var test =  ["14:49", "14:58", "14:57", "14:56", "14:55", "14:54", "14:53", "14:52", "14:51"];
    test.sort(function (a, b) {
      return new Date('1970/01/01 ' + a) - new Date('1970/01/01 ' + b);
    });
    console.log(test);
  }])
</script>
```